# Sliding down and up ListView with additional data (innitialy hidden then after click showing up )

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview, expandablelistview

I want to create some kind of ListView which will be expanding and collapsing after click on one of its item. When item of ListView is expanded show additional data. After I click another one first data collapsing and show actual one. I found one solution (https://github.com/SilenceDut/ExpandableLayout) but I'm thinking that should be other ways to do that without using external library. Am I right ?

P.S sorry for weak english

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Expandable List View:

Tutorial Link :-http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I don't need subitems of my ListView item, but just one box with some information like : "Opening hours"  click --> showing all information in one box.

Comment: Then add one one item in subitem.

Comment: Ofc it's one way